# Frequent human verification

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, draft

I'm getting frequent human verification screen when posting answers. It seem to be due to the new (?) draft feature. Could you please have a look into it?

P.S. funnily enough, I just got human verification screen asking this question.

Comment: Me too! I'm not a robot, I'm a ring!

Comment: I've been getting these all day!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are a logged in user and have >= 200 reputation:

After successfully completing one captcha, we now suppress captcha for 5 minutes on your account.

Comment: What's up with the 5 minute limit? If I were a bot and wanted to spam does that mean I can spam for 5 minutes after completing one captcha? If I were to try to answer a couple of questions where some thought and explanation needs to be in the answer, it probably would take more than 5 minutes to write that answer. Which means I get hit with the captcha every time.

Comment: @robert why would you get the captcha every time? I don't get the captcha every time I answer. Captcha is triggered in part by how fast things are being done; if you are doing things slowly then you won't get it.

Comment: My bad, it was just that I got hit with the captcha several times in a row and it just felt like there was some kind of problem. Then I saw your response and interpreted it the wrong way. I made an assumption based on too little data. It seems to work fine now.

Comment: that's weird because I get the impression that it's when I spend a long time formulating an answer or question that I get the catpcha.

Comment: do you **ever** get a captcha?