# "I am a human being" appearing twice for the same post

Tags: bug, captcha

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it really neccesary to throw us to captchas more than once while asking a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15303/is-it-really-neccesary-to-throw-us-to-captchas-more-than-once-while-asking-a-ques)
>   [captcha appears on meta prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57456/captcha-appears-on-meta-prematurely)

I just tried to post a question and did not fulfill all the requirement. 
The first time my title was too small. I changed this and press "Post Your Question", I came to the "I'm a human being" page. Entered the captcha and got back to my post page where it stated I had to include one of the required tags for StackExchange. 
When I pressed the "Post your question" less then 1 minute later, I got to the "I'm a human being" page. Should I really get to this page twice? Haven't I proven already that I am a human being?

Comment: As shown in [a very similar scenario](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15303/is-it-really-neccesary-to-throw-us-to-captchas-more-than-once-while-asking-a-ques), once you hit 200 reputation then you'll get a 5 minute grace period after the first CAPTCHA. This should prevent you from getting it so rapidly.

Comment: As an aside: see also balpha's [excellent explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635) about line breaks  and paragraph breaks—thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible duplicate - [Frequent human verification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66574/frequent-human-verification)

The frequency of captha verification is more when your reputation is < 200

Comment: Allright. Thnx. I think it is about the same as the question you mention. However, it seems that this user gets it all the time. I only got it when I didn't fulfill all the requirements.