# What is the purpose of flagging two consecutive closed questions?

Tags: support, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flagged posts - Consecutive closed questions - what actions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94756/flagged-posts-consecutive-closed-questions-what-actions)

In the flag page, I noticed a question flagged for the following reason:

[image: screenshot]

[The flagged question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110226/bug-in-commenting-functionality) has been asked 1 hour ago, while [the question linked in the flagging reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77713) has been asked on February 3. Two questions closed as duplicates of two different questions in the last 8 months doesn't seem something to worry about.

What can 10k users do with such flags? What can moderators do with such flags?
Other automatic flags can be useful for something (e.g. I noticed spam posts on Drupal Answers because they were flagged as low quality posts), but I don't see in which way knowing that a user had 2 consecutive questions closed in the last 8 months can be useful, nor do I see what 10k users can do in the short time, considering they cannot see if the user already received that flag.