# Frequent verification on edit

Tags: support, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am not a robot!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot)

Related: [Frequent human verification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66574/frequent-human-verification)

Why is captcha verification coming up more often now?  When I go to edit a question more than once, I get The Page.

This even happens on sites where I am >1k rep.  I hardly think it's necessary; I don't think anyone over 1k rep would spam, especially on editing his own question that he *just* posted.

It's just not a reasonable path for a spammer.

A spammer would probably just *post a spam question*.  Not edit his spam post 2 times in a 3 minute window.

Comment: We're looking at tweaking the captcha rules a bit.